# Create a column of list from another column and display only unique values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new to pandas, I am trying to use group by and create a list of in a new column.
I have 3 columns in my Dataframe and I created a 4th column(New_List) to create a list from another column like below:  using the below code:

new_df = df.join(pd.Series(df.groupby(by='NO_ACCOUNTS').apply(lambda x: list(x.Bucket)), name="list_of_b"), on='NO_ACCOUNTS')

```
Account_Number   Bucket  Number_Transactions     New_List
   ABA            APP          155                 [APP]
   ABC            APP          1352                [APP]
   AAA            APP          90                  [API,APP]
   AAA            API          5                   [API,APP]
```

I am looking to get the desired output with 3 columns:

```
Account_Number     Number_Transactions     New_List
   ABA                      155                 [APP]
   ABC                      1352                [APP]
   AAA                      95                  [API,APP]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `agg`regate the two columns:

```
out = (df.groupby("Account_Number", sort=False, as_index=False)
         .agg(Number_Transactions=("Number_Transactions", "sum"),
              New_List=("Bucket", list)))
```

which first groups by `Account_Number` while keeping their order with `sort=False` and not making it index with `as_index=False`, and then aggregates the `Number_Transactions` column with summation and appoints it to the same name columns and similarly, aggs the `Bucket` column with `list` and assigns it to `New_List` column in the output,

to get

```
>>> out

  Account_Number  Number_Transactions    New_List
0            ABA                  155       [APP]
1            ABC                 1352       [APP]
2            AAA                   95  [APP, API]
```